# Send data to a server using arduino

Tags: php, database, arduino, arduino-uno, sim900

I'm making an Arduino project with involves sending data to a server. I searched up the methods that I could use, and I came across the methods `POST` and `GET`, but I need the information that I'am sending to be untouched and extremely secure! The URL method is easy to be changed or hacked. Is there any other method that I could use to get this information and send to my server?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: If you use the SIM900 module, probably the non-scure protocol is between Arduino and SIM900. If you accept it, the next step is to send the request over GSM and this is done by the SIM900 itself. And this is not easy to "hack" since it is never sent as cleartext. You can increase security by using a 3G or 4G module (SIM7000) or by adding https (not easy with the SSL certificate on the SIM-module, since you have to add it manually).

Answer (score 0):

You protect it the same way you protect any other sensitive Web usage: by using HTTPS instead of insecure HTTP.

Comment: Ok, but can I use the get or post than?

Comment: @NiltonSf Yes, HTTPS still uses the same methods as regular HTTP.

Comment: But, for example, the get method uses the url to get values, Is there a method so i cant let the user change the data from the URL. The only data that the server will accept will be the one send by the arduino

Comment: In order to take data only from arduino you have to use an authorization process with every request from the arduino(client) to your computer (server) you have to send an access token and verify its validity for each request. This token should be encrypted with a secret code that only arduino and your server know.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the request leaves you device either with get or post method from security prespective its the same. The thing you have to consider is using HTTPS because you data travel encrypted (SSL-encryption) and none can read or write them except the receiver/transmmiter.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on Youtube video or a website so I can see a tutorial for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPS and validate the data which comes from the client (in your case client it is Arduino), but anybody can post the data to your url so it's common practice to process and validate only data you expect.

If validation fails return 400 http code.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on Youtube video or a website so I can see a tutorial for that?